# System of three coupled linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Edit: Added a new part to the bottom after doing some thinking

Good day,

I am trying to solve the following system of equations, where all the M's depend on time.

$\dot{M_1} = -p_1M_1 + p_2M_2$

$\dot{M_2} = -(p_2+p_3)M_2 + p_1M_1+p_4M_3$

$\dot{M_3} = -p_4M_3 + p_3M_2$

Now to be honest, I am rather clueless as for where to start. I have solved such a system once before, but that was using an adiabatic approximation, e.g. saying that one of the differential equations was approximately zero on the timescale at which the others change. I don't really have such information now.

However, from the context from which I get the problem I can say that at a certain time, I am in one of the three M's and not in the others. I suppose I could go from there, as a sort of initial condition, and try to go further?

Or perhaps it would be possible to make a simulation of the dynamics instead. I have both matlab and mathematica available, but I an inexperienced with both. This does not mean that I am not able to read documentation of course, so I'll have to look into that. I don't really know where to start, but it seems very plausible that this can be simulated.

**After working on it for a while, with the help of the other posters**
Alright, so I'm not sure if the answer is correct. My answer comes out to be 
[image: equation]

But this can't be right, can it? Because here it seems that if I start in the situation where M1(0) = 1, M2(0)=M3(0) = 0, then the dynamics are very simple: M3(t) is just equal to M1(0) for all time, M1(t) simply exponentially decays, and M2(t) exponentially grows.

This is in no way coupled at all, while they are supposed to depend on each other all throughout their time evolution.

I wrote a matlab script that solves the system for me, and with that it does show the correct dynamics. With equal probabilities, it converges to all three being 0.333 at high times, which is what I want. However, the solver doesn't give me the actual formula's, so I don't see what I did wrong.

My code:

```
%differential numerically
p1 = 0.01;
p2 = 0.05;
p3 = 0.05;
p4 = 0.05;
syms M1(t) M2(t) M3(t)
Y = dsolve(diff(M1) == -p1*M1+p2*M2, diff(M2) == -(p2+p3)*M2+p1*M1+p4*M3, diff(M3) == -p4*M3+p3*M2, M1(0) == 1, M2(0) == 0, M3(0) ==0);
t=linspace(0,500,20000);
M1=eval(vectorize(Y.M1));
M2=eval(vectorize(Y.M2));
M3=eval(vectorize(Y.M3));
figure
plot(t,M1,'b-',t,M2,'g-',t,M3,'r-');
```

Comment: This should have an exact solution as it is linear. Writing it into matrix form is a good start to solve them.

Comment: Are $p_1$, $p_2$, $p_3$, and $p_4$ constants?

Comment: @Kw08 Yes, they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say

> This is in no way coupled at all, while they are supposed to depend on each other all throughout their time evolution.

But this is alright - you hand-picked a particular initial condition that made one of the quantities constant. In general though, the system will still be coupled.

This is related to the fact that, for many linear operators, there is a choice of basis so that the matrix of the linear operator is diagonal.

For instance, given the system
$$
\dot x = 2 x + y, \\
\dot y = x + 2y,
$$
in matrix form this is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\dot x \\ \dot y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}
$$

which has general solution
$$
\begin{pmatrix}x(t) \\ y(t)\end{pmatrix} = c_1\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}e^t + c_2 \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}e^{3t}
$$
and hopefully there's no argument that $x$ and $y$ still look coupled.

However, if we first change variables to 
$$
w = x + y, \\
z = x - y,
$$

then the system can be written
$$
\dot w = \dot x + \dot y = 3x + 3y = 3w \\
\dot z = \dot x - \dot y = x - y = z
$$
and we have effectively decoupled the system; i.e. the corresponding matrix equation would be diagonal, and it's pretty clear that $w$ and $z$ are independent.

EDIT: to compute the matrix exponential of your system (let's assume all the $p_i$'s are equal), find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of 
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}-p & p & 0 \\ p & -2p & p \\ 0 & p & -p \end{bmatrix} = p\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

which are $0, -p, -3p$. The corresponding eigenvectors are
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix},
$$
so solutions are 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}e^{-pt}, \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}e^{-3pt},
$$
We could get *a* fundamental matrix by taking these solutions as columns, but we want a fundamental matrix so that at $t=0$ we get the identity. One way to do this is to solve initial value problems for $(1,0,0)^T$, $(0,1,0)^T$ and $(0,0,1)^T$, then use those solutions as the columns.

Comment: Hmm. I'll have to think about this for a bit I think, because I do not completely understand. From a completely heuristic point of view, if M2 increases depending on the amount of M1 present, an initial condition of only M1 would imply, to me, that M2 grows. Thus at a later time, there will be M2 as well as M1. However, now M2 will also start changing into M3, corresponding to the rate p3. So at an even later time, there will be M3 as well. But the way it works if I plot the equations, these dynamics are not visible at all.

Comment: Ah, a comment on the first point has explained what is wrong. My confusion came due to a computational error on my part. 
Your explanation makes total sense now, thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah, I think you have the wrong solution in your question. In particular, if you compute $e^{At}$, you should get $I$ for $t=0$. Further, you have an obvious conflict between initial data $M_3(0) = 1$ and the "solution" $M_3 \equiv M_1(0) = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider the matrix form of the problem, since it is linear. Indeed, if $\vec{M} = M_i$, then:

$$\frac{d\vec{M}}{dt} = A \vec{M} =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc} -p1 & p_2 & 0 \\ p_1 & -(p_2+p_3) & p_4 \\ 0 & p_3 & -p_4 \end{array}  \right) \, \vec{M}.$$

Hence, the matrix $\Phi(t) = e^{t A}$ (exponential matrix) is said to be a fundamental matrix of the sistem, and the solution becomes:

$$M(t) = \Phi(t) \, \vec{C},$$

where $\vec{C} = C_i$ is the vector of constants of integration.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you both, I'll try and work this out and see how I fare.

Comment: You're welcome! You can also try to implement this problem in Matlab so you can check wether the analytical and numerical solution give the same results.

Comment: Yes, I'll indeed do that, as at some point I'll have to fit the solution to data in order to obtain p1, p2 and p3, but that is an entirely different matter. For now, I was indeed able to work it out, and it makes a lot of sense. I am a bit ashamed that I couldn't think of this myself.

However, if I am not mistaken this thus means that for example M1 would depend on the constant of integration of M3, and the other way around. This feels a bit weird. I'll have to think on that a bit. In any case, thanks for answering the question!

Comment: You're welcome again! The constant of integration, $C$, is related to the initial conditions, so if $\vec{M}(t_0) = \vec{M}_0$, then: $\vec{M}(t) = \Phi(t) \Phi^{-1}(t_0) \vec{M}_0$. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, then it makes perfect sense.

Comment: Although, it's not actually working. In the solutions in this form, there isn't really a sort of 'feedback' between the functions, is there? As in, if the system starts out in m1, then it should after some time depending on p1 go into m2. Then in m2, it should go either into m1 or m3, again. But these are just independent exponentials. Am I missing something?

This is assuming c1 = 1, and c2 = c3 = 0, by the way, so the system starts out in m1.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by saying "starts in $M_1$ and then go into $M_2$". This problem represents the evolution in time of a dynamical system where its state variables, $M_i(t)$, are related through the differential equations above. This feedback you pointed out before is then given by these relations (equations). I hope this helps you a bit. EDIT: An example of what I'm saying might be this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equation, which models the evolution in time of the population of a pray and a predator. Cheers!

Comment: Hm, I'll attempt to clarify. 
This system of equations describes the following situation.
The system can be in three states. It can be in state M1, M2 or M3. From state 1, it can go into state 2 with probability p1. From state 2 it can go into state 1 with probability p2, and into state 3 with probability p3. From state three it can go into state 2 with probability p4.

Now in reality, this is a discrete process, as in it can only be in one of the three states at the same time. However, I thought that this could be approximated by this system of coupled differential equations.

Comment: Well, then I think the continous approximation may not be very useful by the fact you mention. Presumably, the solution of the ODEs is smooth for any $t\geq 0$ so there might be some $t^*$ where $M_i \neq 0$ for any combination of two states. Sorry I cannot help you with modelling the discrete-probabilty problem since it's not my field of knowledge. Cheers!

Comment: That is perfectly fine, thank you in any case!

Comment: Alright, so I've worked out a matlab script to compare it to, and things aren't working out sadly. So I've updated the main post with my progress.

Comment: Hi there! Take into acount that the computation of the matrix exponential, $e^{tA}$, is not achieved by exponentiating every entry of $tA$. This is wrong!! By definition, $e^{X} = I + X + X^2/2! + X^3/3! + \ldots$, but it's more convenient to compute $e^{tA}$ in terms of the Jordan canonical form or with the help of the Lagrange-Sylvester polynomial. Cheers!

Comment: Wow, I did not know that. That changes everything.